# iPhone: how to reload tableView and push a detailView from AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios-4.2, delegation

my app is nav based. in which i have a main tableView which shows feed items in cells. when a cell is clicked, a detailview is created which shows details of that feed item. i am working with push notifications now. when action button in notification is clicked,

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo:
```

is called. how can i implement that method that if action button in notification is clicked. it should parse the feed again, reload the tableview, creates the latest feed items detailview and push it in navigational stack. i tried some code but it didn't work. here is the code i wrote.

in AppDelegate:

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
               RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
               [controller newFeedItem];
     }
```

in RootViewController:

```
    - (void)newFeedItem
    {
        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame=CGRectMake(130, 170, 50, 50);
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];

[self performSelector:@selector(doStuff) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
  }

  -(void)doStuff
  {

   [[self stories] removeAllObjects];
   [self startParsing];
   [self.tableView reloadData];
// create detailview and push it in navigational stack
       [spinner stopAnimating];
   [spinner release];
 }
```

but activity indicator is not appearing and tableView is also not reloading. Why is it happening so? Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about your program flow but I assume you show the rootViewController at program start and at a later time you receive a remote notification.

In your code (in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`) you are instantiating a new rootViewController and that new one will be different from the one already on the screen. Following your approach you might want alloc the controller once and keep it around for later when the remote notification arrives.

Personally I would suggest to use local notifications and to fire a local notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and catch it in the rootViewController. That would ensure the currently active instance of the controller responds.

Also not sure why the spinner not shows, for a try call it from the `viewDidAppear`, just it see it it works at all and if the problem is with the reaction to the remote notification. And use some breakpoints.

---

Edit  with respect to your comment:

in the interface define

`RootViewController *controller`

in the implementation you alloc the controller (for example in `appDidFininshLaunching`)

```
 if (controller == nil) controller =  [[RootViewController alloc] init]
```

in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` you can then do

```
           [controller newFeedItem];
```

without alloc'ing it again and you can refer to the same controller. Don't forget to release it in `-(void)dealloc`

Comment: well if i ll not instantiate a new rootViewController, how ll i parse the feed again. all parsing is happening in rootViewController. is it possible to write some code in didReceiveRemoteNotification that ll access the rootViewController the one i already have?

Comment: yup i show the rootViewController at program start and at a later time i recieve remote notification. and i want tableView to be reload when action button in notification is clicked.

Comment: please see the edits to my answer on how to reuse the controller